# NGinx limit_conn for $request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

I have some video files on my server and I'm trying to limit the number of connections for each video. If I use `$binary_remote_addr` the user cannot download other video files at the same time. I want to restrict based on link address instead of `binary_remote_addr`. Do you think this is possible? Can it be done using `map`?

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

limit_conn addr 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any key you want, like:

```
limit_conn_zone $request_uri zone=uri:10m;
limit_conn uri 1;
```

This will allow only one connection per request URI at a time. Increase the value `1` to your needs.

Comment: I didn't think it would be this easy =) Thanks... @CrazyRabbit